# What should I do to fix all these weird LAN problems

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan

My home network has been having some weird issues. I'm having issues with the WLAN (the wired part of the LAN is fine). The internet has been really slow for some people in my house despite a recent upgrade of our router and broadband. Loading web pages and surfing the web is fine, but streaming of any kind or online gaming have taken a hit. Here's a list of the things that are out of the norm:

- I sent 4 ICMP echo pings from router to a smartphone at one poing. Lost 2/4 of them.
- Doing a traceroute from router to the same smartphone mentioned above was inconsistent or nonresponsive.
- Router stats showed very low data throughput. (Average throughput over 24 hours for 2.4 GHz WiFi was ~46,000 bps, 5 GHz was ~1,288,215. At the time of measurement for 2.4 GHz it was 5908 bps, 5 GHz was 61. Three times 2.4 GHz reported 0 bps.)
- I did a packet capture from my desktop with wireshark. The router sent an ARP request for every single IP address in my /24 network except its own. For those who don't know that's 253 ARP requests in a row. I didn't count but it did this at least 4-5 times in less than 10 minutes of capturing. I'm no system admin but I'm pretty sure that's not supposed to happen.
- Also on packet capture there was a lot (I think) of ICMPv6 Neighbor Solicitations from the router. Approximately 9,000 of them in 10 minutes.

I did a traceroute outside our network and it seemed fine. Speed test also seemed fine. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You provided a lot of circumstantial evidence that may or may not be related to your problem. Let’s start at the beginning. It sounds like you are having significant WiFi connectivity troubles. What have you done to specifically address that issue? Checked signal strengths? Scanned for nearby networks interfering? Tried quality/speed tests on different bands and/or different channels and/or different locations and distances?

Comment: The ARP requests suggest that the router is trying to locate computers on the network with those IP addresses.  That's unusual unless there is a computer that is performing a network scan (e.g. nmap), possibly the router.  For WiFi performance, can you see how many / what computers are connected using WiFi, and whether there are too many WiFi networks nearby on the same / nearby channels?

Comment: The evidence is circumstantial, true. These symptoms may or may not be the same problem. I checked signal strength (on 2.4 GHz) not long ago and it was fine. Above average actually. Nearby networks are a good possibility since I live in an urban area with lots of people nearby. It's probably wireless related since the ethernet connection seems ok. I've considered the possibility of an ARP scan (I'm into pentesting type stuff), but I don't know what to do about it. Like I said there are a lot of wifi networks nearby. At least 6 or so.